# Java Hibernate HQL SQL INNER JOIN query not working- Oracle

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Hibernate / Java newbie here, any help will be greatly appreciated!

So...... I have a table called ITEMS and a ITEM_OWNER_JOIN table joined by the

"itemKey" column and the "owners" column which is a Set of String values...

In Item.java I have:

```
@ForeignKey(name="FK_ITEM_OWNER_FK")
@ElementCollection(targetClass=java.lang.String.class, fetch = FetchType.Eager)
@JoinTable(name= "ITEM_OWNER_JOIN", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="itemKey"))
private Set<String> owners = new HashSet<String>();
```

and basically I'm trying to run a HQL querying for results where the owners match a 
searchText param....

so I've tried:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select distinct i.itemKey from Item i inner join"+  
          " i.owners o where o.owners like '"+searchText+"'");
```

and I am getting a org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection element: owners [select distinct w.workspaceKey from.....]

I've tried researching for that exception to no avail... :(

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something as below

**HQL**

```
select i 
from Item i 
inner join i.owners io 
where io like 'searchText';
```

**Oracle Query**

```
SELECT Distinct(i.itemKey) 
FROM Item i, ITEM_OWNER_JOIN io 
WHERE i.itemKey  = io.itemKey and io.x like '%%';
```

where 'x' is column name.

Working example from my application

From entity:

```
 @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "rule_tagged_name", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "re_rule", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<String>         ruleTagNames;
```

**DB Columns**

```
RE_RULE NUMBER
RULE_TAG_NAMES
```

**HQL**

```
Select ru FROM Rule ru inner join ru.ruleTagNames rt_name WHERE rt_name in :tagNameList
```

Comment: Thank you! changing io.owners to io just before the like fixed the error, do you guys know why it is throwing that error? I have a column named "owners" inside the ITEM_OWNER_JOIN table since the column was not explicitly annotated. Maybe it is confused because the Set of Strings "owners" and the join table's column "owners" is named the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try using with `IN` operator as `owners` is multiple.

```
Query hqlQuery = session.createQuery("select distinct i.itemKey from Item i inner join"+  
      " i.owners o where o.owners in :ownersParam");
```

Then set parameter `owners` with the owner set value,

```
Set<String> ownerSet = new HashSet<String>();
ownerSet.add(searchText);

hqlQuery.setParameterList("ownersParam", ownerSet);

//then retrieve result
```